# How to remove an unsuccessful installation of Java 6

Tags: installation, apt, java, jdk

I unsuccessfully tried installing Java 6 by copy-pasting the following from http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/oracle-sun-java-6-installer-available.html in the terminal window:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java6-installer
```

It was running well until it came to a point where something like [connecting elibrary.oracle.com...connected] showed up (sorry I can't remember it correctly). There it was stuck for a good 3 hours. So I had to close the Terminal down, thereby killing the process midway.

Can anyone please tell me how to remove anything that has already been installed and take the system back to the state it was before attempting this installation.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Regards,
Bob.

Comment: You want to give up completely, or you want to fix this installation? Repeating the `apt-get install` step might fix it. Or you could try to remove the broken package with `apt-get remove --purge oracle-java6-installer`

Comment: I basically wanted to remove the broken package altogether and then try a fresh install with another ppa. So I think I'll try apt-get remove...also if you could suggest me another way to install Java 6 with browser plug-ins for I need it for work purposes. And I highly appreciate you answering my query. This community is the best thing about Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 4):

First, remove the PPA, you won't need it anymore :

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

The, remove the package and purge the configuration files :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge oracle-java6-installer
```

Finally, if it did manage to get to the point where it modifies the system itself :

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove-all java
```

You then can clean the cache :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Tada ! Back to a clean system !

Comment: Thanks a billion for the help.I appreciate the fact that it is so very systematically explained.Now everything went well but I need to mention a few things..When I type in [ sudo update-alternatives --remove-all java ] this is the response [update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for java.]. And when I type in [sudo apt-get autoclean] the response is [Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Del oracle-java6-installer 6u45-0~webupd8~3 [17.9 kB].

Comment: Does this mean the job is done because when I open the Dash and type Java I can still see a lot of Java 6 icons for eg. Oracle Java 6 Console, Oracle Java 6 Visual VM,  Oracle Java 6 Plugin Control Panel, etc. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: what does `sudo update-alternatives --display java`, `java -version` and `dpkg -l | grep java` say ?